# How to get all seller listings?

Tags: amazon-mws

I need to get data about all listings in my Amazon Seller Central account.

I checked the available reports that Amazon can generate, and the best is the open listings report - best - I mean that it gives more data than other reports, but still lacks much, for example, EANs, photo URLs.

However, the open listings report have one issue: It crops the long titles of the listings and places a "..." postfix. It also adds a product type string to the titles, like "Title [Electronics]".

So, while the open listings report can be used as "something is better than nothing", I need something more decent.

Is there something else that can be used to accomplish my task, or is that report is the best I can get?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can request a "_GET_MERCHANT_LISTINGS_DATA_" report from Amazon MWS, which will give you the most data, including the photo URLs.

Unfortunately, the title data is still shortened and the product type is still added.

A list of all inventory reports can be found in the [documentation](http://s3.amazonaws.com/devo.docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_DE/reports/Reports_ReportType.html).

You could also try using the [Products API](http://s3.amazonaws.com/devo.docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_DE/products/Products_Overview.html).

This will give you very detailed data about each product with the correct titles, but you have to send a query to get results instead of getting everything in a single report.

Comment: Broken links in answer.

Comment: @AviadP. I've updated the links to what appears to be the current docs.

Answer (score 0):

As this question is old, I got here through another doubt.

Nowadays we are using the [SP-API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs.)

If you want the listing information with the SKU just use the amazon [LISTING-API](https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/listings-items-api-v2021-08-01-use-case-guide) getListingItems endpoint

Comment: I was able to use the "get Listings Item" in postman to get details on a specific listing, do you know how to get a list of all listings?  If my app gets disconnected during listing and there is a live listing that it doesn't know about, how can it poll all active listings to verify it knows about all of them? i.e. How do you get all listings like the OP wanted using SP-API?